# How to do RSA same message attack?

Tags: attacks, vulnerability, rsa

I found that I can attack texts that crypted by RSA with different public key, and same plain text.
But I can't find how to decrypt them.

So, how to attack them, and what is decrypted number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let m be the message. Let m1, m2, m3 be the modulus of the three public keys. Notice that all three of them have e = 3 as their public exponent.

The ciphertext for each recipient is computed as

[image: crt1]

We know each c_i, m_i and (m^3 mod m_i). We thus have three equations which describe the identity of m^3 in three modular rings.

[image: crt2]

We solve the system of equations using the *Chinese Remainder Theorem* (CRT). The CRT states in this case that the identity of m^3 modulo the product of all modului can be reconstructed by using the formula

[image: crt]

Since we now know m^3, we can reconstruct m by computing the third root of m^3 over the integers. And thus we have reconstructed m.

This is also known as "low exponent attack" on RSA ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#Low_public_exponent_attack)) and has been discussed on the crypto exchange before ([here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/low-public-exponent-attack-for-rsa))